# Receiving odd error while downloading PRISM climate data. How to download a list of dates?

Tags: r, code-climate

Trying to get mean temperature for a certain date over the last 5 years. Keep running into this same error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
get_prism_dailys(type="tmean", dates = as.Date("2018-06-01", "2017-06-01", "2016-06-01", "2015-06-01", "2014-06-01"), keepZip=FALSE)
```

Error Received:

> Error in if (!is_within_daily_range(dates)) stop("Please ensure all dates fall within the valid Prism data record") : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 0):

The short answer on you question is quite simple: just replace `as.Date` with the `c()` function:

```
get_prism_dailys(type = "tmean", dates = as.Date("2018-06-01", "2017-06-01", 
    "2016-06-01", "2015-06-01", "2014-06-01"), keepZip=FALSE)
```

It seems to me that the third examples to `get_prism_dailys()`, which you have probably used, has a small issue. Lets's see on the source code `get_prism_dailys()`, which is possible with

```
print(get_prism_dailys)
```

The `dates` argument is processed `get_prism_dailys()` with the `gen_dates()` function:

> `dates <- gen_dates(minDate = minDate, maxDate = maxDate, dates = dates)`

In its turn, the `gen_dates()` is transforming the dates argument with `as.Dates()`, as we can find with getAnywhere():

```
getAnywhere(gen_dates)
```

> ```
> if(!is.null(dates)){    
>     # make sure it is cast as a date if it was provided as a character
>     dates <- as.Date(dates)
> ```

Thus, the transformation of the `date` input with `as.Date()` is not necessary, but it is essential to put all the supplied dates into a single vector.

Hope, it will be helpful :)